# deleteDoc() gets TypeError and not deleting document from firestore db in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and quite new to react, I'm developing a shopping list app. I add documents to my db using `setDoc()` like that:

```
const addToFirestore = async () => {
    if (tilesToDB.indexOf(tile) === -1) {
        setTilesToDB((prev) => [...prev, tile]);
        await setDoc(doc(db, 'list', tile.contents), tile);     
    } 
}
```

The item is added either by clicking on the add button or by clicking outside input field after typing item's name.
When i try to delete document in similar fashion, by deleteDoc():

```
const removeFromFirestore = async (id) => {
  const docRef = (db, 'list', id);
  await deleteDoc(docRef).then(() => {
    console.log("Entire Document has been deleted successfully.")
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error); 
  });
}
```

and then calling the above function by clicking remove button:

```
onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(tile.id, 'tile to remove');
                    setItems(items.filter((el, i) => i !== items.indexOf(tile)));
                    removeFromFirestore(tile.contents);
                    console.log('test', items);
                  }
```

i get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_delegate' in undefined`
The rest of the code works fine, including the `setItems()` call in above function, which deletes item in the browser, but it's not subsequently deleted from db. the `console.log` call shows that the right document id is being passed to `deleteDoc()`. I also made sure to have all the relevant imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `async/await` and `.then()/.catch()`.  You do NOT want to do this.  You will not be happy with the results.

Simply change your code to:

```js
const removeFromFirestore = async (id) => {
  const docRef = (db, 'list', id);
  try {
    await deleteDoc(docRef)
    console.log("Entire Document has been deleted successfully.");
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex); 
  }
}
```

Later in your code you call: `removeFromFirestore(tile.contents);`  Is `tile.contents` a valid `id` value, which is what `removeFromFirestore()` is expecting?

You might consider doing a `console.log('docRef path is', docRef.path)` inside `removeFromFirestore()` right after giving docRef a value, just to be sure that it is the path you expect it to be.